# Azure Function or Azure Function project in VS Code solution if I need the function to access other projects in the solution

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I know I'll probably get slapped down for this post, but I need to know how to do it properly.

My website is a .Net web project in a folder with this structure.

- .sln - file
- API - folder (contains controllers, DTO's, extensions, .csproj - Sdk.Web)
- Client - folder (contains Angular project)
- Core (.Net Sdk) - folder that contains entities, enums, interfaces, .csproj -> .Sdk
- Infrastructure (.Net Sdk) - folder that contains dataContext.cs, migration files, services, .csproj -> .Sdk

**Problem** - Currently I have a controller that accepts a webhook for Stripe and I want to offload this webhook out of my website controller and into a Azure Function, this new Azure function will need to access my business entities (Core) and my database (Infrastructure) to run business logic before saving to the DB, so

**Question** - I'm not sure if I need to create an Azure project in my solution in it's own folder (call it AZFunctions), outside the solution or just an Azure function file somewhere in an already existing project?

**Concerns** - I'm using a EF code first approach, so when I change an entity then migrate and update my DB, won't the Azure Function fail if it's deployed? If I create a new Azure Function project in a new folder in my solution, the new project has a local.settings.json file that would be separate from my appsettings.json file in my API.

Comment: If I were you I would just share models , maybe put them inside nugget package ! Create a different db context maybe with some lightweight ORM just azure functions. Whenever u change you entities u can just update your nugget package inside the az function project and make necessary changes and redeploy az functions.

Comment: I'm handling such cases just as @J.Memisevic already mentioned.
In a solution, I simply add a "Shared Project" with all the DTO's and reuse them in all the projects required (for cross solution access I would also go for NuGet).
And as the Azure Functions are created as a separate project (with individual settings in the *.csproj file), I would just go for <Name-of-your-Solution>.Functions (or [Micro-]Services) and reference the other stuff as you like.

Comment: @DSpirit agree , and if you use different db context and there is no changes in those models there is no rush in updating your az functions , because in your az function db context u gonna have just models need for function to work .

Comment: @DSpirit When you say "shared project" do you mean just another project in my solution? More specifically, should I create a func project or just a generic project in the solution? Will adding a Azure function to a generic project work? Doesn't it have to be a func project?

Comment: A function app project is as it's name already says a function app project. In a solution, you can have several different projects, one of them would be the FunctionApp itself.
You can choose which project should be run in Visual Studio by right-clicking it and setting "Set as startup project".
For more information about the Shared Projects, check this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows